# I recently format my hard disk, But my project was in another Drive. But I get this Node error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently format my hard disk, But my project was in another Drive. But I get this Node error?

```
G:\co\NodeJs\project\node_modules\require_optional\node_modules\resolve-from\index.js:1SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 

(G:\co\NodeJs\project\node_modules\require_optional\index.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling the `resolve-from` module and/or the `require-optional` module since those look like the source of the error.

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried but it still shows same error

Comment: Well, what's on line 1 of `G:\co\NodeJs\project\node_modules\require_optional\node_modules\resolve-from\index.js`?  It's apparently something node.js does not like.  Also, what version of nodejs?

Comment: @jfriend00 That file is empty and node version is v12.18.3

Comment: Well, that file isn't supposed to be empty.  [Here's](https://github.com/sindresorhus/resolve-from/blob/master/index.js) what it's supposed to be.  Something is not installed correctly.  You should update or reinstall all dependent modules or manually fix this particular module.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently your `G:\co\NodeJs\project\node_modules\require_optional\node_modules\resolve-from\index.js` file is blank, but it is supposed to have [this content](https://github.com/sindresorhus/resolve-from/blob/master/index.js).

So, something is not installed correctly.  You should either reinstall all your dependent modules or manually fix this particular module.  I'd suggest uninstalling and then reinstalling this module as a first step.  If errors show up somewhere else, then perhaps remove all dependent modules from NPM and reinstall all of them.